# Can I upload file from my computer to aws s3 using aws-sdk?

Tags: amazon-s3

I tried upload file from local to aws s3 use aws-sdk but I get error: Access Denied. I attached the AmazonS3FullAccess policy. I'm using terminal to run code. `php upload.php`

My code:

```
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

// Set Amazon s3 credentials
$client = S3Client::factory(
  array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => "mykey",
        'secret' => "myscret",
    ),   
    'region' => "ap-southeast-1",
    'version' => "latest"
  )
);

try {
  $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'=>'mybucket',
    'Key' => 'text.txt',
    'Body' => 'Hello, world!',
    'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    's3'=>'PutObject'
    // 'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
  ));

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  // Catch an S3 specific exception.
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Try copying the file using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command using the same credentials. This will help isolate the problem. Is the destination bucket in the same AWS Account as the credentials you are using?

Comment: Side-note: Are you running this code on an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, you should not put Access Key/Secret Key in the code. Simply assigned an IAM Role to the instance and it will automatically receive credentials. See: [Credentials for the AWS SDK for PHP version 3 - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html)